# Check for a minus value iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am crunching some numbers and now I want to check if my output is in a specific range from -0.1 to -1.08, but somehow this never gets triggered even doe the output in the console is clearly between does numbers.

_motionLastYaw is of a type **float**

Here is how I check my number range:

```
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    if (_motionLastYaw >= -0.1 && _motionLastYaw <= -1.08) {
        NSLog(@"between LEFT");
    }
```

And yes the UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft is getting triggered correctly

Console output:

```
[5093:2064019] motionLatYaw -0.057875
[5093:2064019] motionLatYaw -0.057546
[5093:2064019] motionLatYaw -0.057420
[5093:2064019] motionLatYaw -0.057468
[5093:2064019] motionLatYaw -0.057598
[5093:2064019] motionLatYaw -0.057772
```

Comment: `-0.1` is greater than `-1.08` you know... your check should be reversed: `_motionLastYaw <= -0.1 && _motionLastYaw >= -1.08`

Comment: @poncha omfg pace palm^100 thanks allot please feel free to post this as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `-0.1` is greater than `-1.08` the check should be reversed:

```
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
  if (_motionLastYaw <= -0.1 && _motionLastYaw >= -1.08) {
    NSLog(@"between LEFT");
  }
}
```